# Move files on windows7 ntfs dead slow?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

Just installed Win7, and i noticed when i move a file/folder, it actually copies, then deletes.  I noticed because if i want to move 40 GB, I must have 40 GB free space.

On XP, if I am moving folders and files within the same partition, no matter size, are moved instantly. Only the number of files matters.
Any way to get around this?
Thanks.
**Edit1:** No, not using any software, just the native windows explorer file manager. I do not know if it is related, but i followed [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/8187/whats-the-best-way-to-move-c-users-to-d-users-under-vista-w7) guide to move C:\Users to the D:\ partition.
**Edit2:** Fixed, If i navigate D:\Users\UserID\Downloads, moving files is instant. But If i try to move navigating from the left hand panel directly to Downloads, even though it is actually on the D: drive, its dead slow. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a file inside the same file system should not actually involve copying and deleting but merely a change in the file system's records of the file. No matter what the file system actually is.

- Do you use a *third party program* to move the file? If yes, try Windows Explorer or the command line.
- If not, please verify that you are absolutely positively sure that *source and destination partitions are identical* when moving the file on Win7.

Answer (score 0):

That does not sound right. Can you try the move command from the CMD window.  Also worth trying a third party util which I find handy for large moves and copies... teracopy